# ERRORSQLSTATE[23000] Aún no encuentro la solucion de esto ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

> ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add
>   or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`blog`.`entradas`, CONSTRAINT `entradas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`blog`.`entradas`, CONSTRAINT `entradas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)ERRORSQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column
>   list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row
>   1ERRORSQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list:
>   1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
CREATE DATABASE blog    
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

USE blog;

CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    nombre VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    fecha_registro DATETIME NOT NULL,
    activo TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE entradas (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        activa TINYINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(autor_id)
            REFERENCES usuarios(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT 
);

CREATE TABLE comentarios (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        entrada_id INT NOT NULL,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, 
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(autor_id)
            REFERENCES usuarios(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
        FOREIGN KEY(entrada_id)
            REFERENCES entradas(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: tengo el mismo error, no has podido solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`entradas`, CONSTRAINT `entradas` FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`entradas`, CONSTRAINT `entradas` FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)ERRORSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.comentarios' doesn't existERRORSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.comentarios' doesn't exist

> Sigue dando este mismo error

Intento introducir unos datos en masa y este es mi script de relleno para los datos en masa.

```
<?php

include_once 'app/config.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Conexion.inc.php';

include_once 'app/Usuario.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Entrada.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Comentario.inc.php';

include_once 'app/RepositorioUsuario.inc.php';
include_once 'app/RepositorioEntrada.inc.php';
include_once 'app/RepositorioComentario.inc.php';

Conexion::abrir_conexion();

for ($usuarios = 0; $usuarios < 2; $usuarios++) {
    $nombre = sa(10);
    $email = sa(5).'@'.sa(3);
    $password = password_hash('12345678', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $usuario = new Usuario('', $nombre, $email, $password, '', '');

    RepositorioUsuario :: insertar_usuario(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $usuario);
}

for ($entradas = 0; $entradas < 2; $entradas++) {
    $titulo = sa(10);
    $texto = lorem();
    $autor = rand(1, 100);

    $entrada = new Entrada('', $autor, $titulo, $texto, '', '');

    RepositorioEntrada :: insertar_entrada(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $entrada);
}

for ($comentarios = 0; $comentarios < 2; $comentarios++) {
    $titulo = sa(10);
    $texto = lorem();
    $autor = rand(1, 100);
    $entrada = rand(1,100);

    $comentario = new Comentario('', $autor, $entrada, $titulo, $texto, '');

    RepositorioComentario :: insertar_comentario(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $comentario);
}

function sa($longitud) {
    $caracteres = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvWxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $numero_caracteres = strlen($caracteres);
    $string_aleatrorio = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud; $i++) {
        $string_aleatrorio .= $caracteres[rand(0, $numero_caracteres - 1)];
    }

    return $string_aleatrorio;
}

function lorem() {
    $lorem = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec libero eu odio elementum hendrerit. Aliquam sed sagittis lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque ac augue leo. Morbi fringilla neque at neque imperdiet, et tincidunt mi euismod. Duis vulputate eleifend leo, ac laoreet ligula vulputate eu. Aliquam erat volutpat.

Donec eget dui iaculis, convallis est sed, bibendum tellus. Phasellus a sagittis odio, ac luctus lorem. Nam odio metus, maximus sed massa quis, convallis laoreet quam. Donec consectetur interdum justo, nec posuere metus aliquet id. Quisque molestie nulla nec mollis sodales. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec et dapibus tortor. Duis ac dapibus orci. Cras tristique a dolor at dignissim. Vestibulum imperdiet tellus nec rutrum fringilla. Praesent maximus turpis ac mauris malesuada, sit amet luctus justo viverra. Mauris rutrum sit amet nisi ut suscipit. Nullam pulvinar lectus et orci sagittis aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Pellentesque porta interdum neque sed posuere. Ut id ligula non lectus tempor venenatis. Cras porttitor tortor ligula, at consectetur tortor fermentum eget. Quisque a mi vel quam lacinia laoreet. Nulla laoreet vehicula elit, vel aliquam augue rutrum sed. Mauris tincidunt, massa in bibendum sodales, tortor arcu hendrerit turpis, id eleifend elit felis nec mi. Vivamus ultricies sollicitudin dictum.

Sed ac magna id purus sodales dignissim non vel orci. Mauris a ex enim. Integer accumsan dapibus blandit. Etiam suscipit lacinia est pharetra varius. Donec pellentesque lorem vitae metus fermentum, sit amet pharetra augue egestas. Etiam a commodo sapien. Quisque ultricies, libero nec pretium pulvinar, est turpis laoreet nisi, nec vulputate dui augue non dolor. Nunc maximus massa vel iaculis varius. Donec vestibulum auctor nisi a tempus. Pellentesque finibus lectus vitae lacus dignissim, non pharetra purus commodo. Donec eros tellus, pellentesque vitae lobortis a, varius vitae turpis. Cras aliquet rhoncus augue in scelerisque.

Morbi vitae felis eleifend, gravida elit et, fringilla ligula. Pellentesque facilisis imperdiet arcu et aliquet. Sed porta nunc sed eros pulvinar iaculis. Nam semper sapien arcu, ut placerat nulla viverra non. Praesent porta, dolor eu semper finibus, odio nisl faucibus magna, nec hendrerit tortor metus at nisi. Cras neque mi, rhoncus id maximus ut, interdum ac mauris. Nunc tellus massa, aliquam quis neque quis, efficitur aliquam erat. Nulla facilisi.

';

    return $lorem;
}
```

esta es mi actual base de datos.

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    nombre VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    fecha_registro DATETIME NOT NULL,
    activo TINYINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE entradas (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        activa TINYINT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT entradas_usuarios FOREIGN KEY(autor_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE comentarios (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        entrada_id INT NOT NULL,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, 
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        CONSTRAINT comentarios_usuarios FOREIGN KEY(autor_id)
            REFERENCES usuarios(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
        CONSTRAINT comentarios_entradas FOREIGN KEY(entrada_id)
            REFERENCES entradas(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Me da el error de arriba al intentar introducir los datos en masa para yo testear

Answer (score 0):

Tenia un error similar, prueba cambiando lo siguiente en la base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE entradas (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
        activa TINYINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE comentarios (
        id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
        autor_id INT NOT NULL,
        entrada_id INT NOT NULL,
        titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: deberías indicar que cambiaste